# tcp server ip address

Tags: h2

When starting H2 tcp server and the host pc has multiple IP address's how can I define the IP that the server  is going to bind to listen for connections ?
We can define the tcp port but there does not seems to be a way to define the ip address.
Thank you, Oscar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#server_bind_address

> Usually server sockets accept connections on any/all local addresses.
>   This may be a problem on multi-homed hosts. To bind only to one
>   address, use the system property **h2.bindAddress**. This setting is used
>   for both regular server sockets and for SSL server sockets. IPv4 and
>   IPv6 address formats are supported.