# H2 database suddenly running on public localhost address instead of localhost

Tags: h2

After a fresh OS install, I'm launching my project which starts an H2 server usually on `127.0.0.1:9092` but now it's starting on my C class IP address of my local area network.

I didn't changed anything but reinstalling the OS.

I thought about firewall rules so I allowed private and public networks for Java but it didn't changed anything.

I'm starting my H2 server like this :

```java
    public static void start(Runnable r) {
        try {
            Server h2Server =
                Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort",
                                       "9092"
                );
            System.out.println(h2Server.getURL());
            System.out.println(h2Server.getService().getName());
            h2Server.start();
            if (h2Server.isRunning(true)) {
                System.out.println("H2 server was started and is running.");
                onShutdown = h2Server::stop;
            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not start H2 server.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to start H2 server: ", e);
        }
        Database.onStartup = r;
        applicationContext =
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(Database.class)
                .properties(properties()).web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF).run();
    }
```

Does anyone already had this issue?

Thanks for any idea.

---

EDIT :

Console output.

```
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ launcher ---
tcp://192.168.1.36:9092  <-- it was 127.0.0.1:9092 before !!!
H2 TCP Server
H2 server was started and is running.
```

Comment: Presumably it's binding to the first network adapter it finds, which used to be the loopback/localhost device but is now a physical one.  You probably want to look in the docs for how to specify the IP address that it binds to.

Comment: Indeed, it was working fine on Linux but now it's on class C IP address after reinstalling Windows. I found how to set the desired IP address. Thanks for putting me onto the right path.

Comment: I've not used H2 before so didn't know what to refer to, but glad it helped!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319437/1358308 seems relevant and includes a quote the docs

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer here : *Presumably it's binding to the first network adapter it finds, which used to be the loopback/localhost device but is now a physical one. You probably want to look in the docs for how to specify the IP address that it binds to.*

So I forced the desired address with the system property `h2.bindAddress` as suggested in the [docs](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/releases/download/version-2.2.220/h2.pdf) (p. 159).

```java
System.setProperty("h2.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1");
Server h2Server =
    Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
```

And it's working fine now.

```
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ launcher ---
tcp://localhost:9092
H2 TCP Server
H2 server was started and is running.
```